# Fill Vector3 array

Tags: three.js

I have loaded some coordinates from file

```
var koloader = new THREE.FileLoader();
    koloader.load('Koordinate.txt',
    function ( data ) {
    // output the text to the console
    const kord = data.split('\n').map(line =>line.trim()).map(line => line
  .split(' ')                // split by ' '
  .map(parseFloat),line => line
  .split(' ')                // split by ' '
  .map(parseFloat))               // and parse the parts to numbers
.map(([ x, y, z]) => ({ x, y, z }));
```

kord[0].x is my first x in file, kord[0].y is my first y in file,..

I want to set my  vector3's with loop

```
for( let i = 0; i < kord.length; i++){
//missing 
}
```

I have tried `vec3t.set(kord[i].x,kord[i].y,kord[i].z);` but this overwrites my data
.. I want to have like this:
Vector3[0].x = 1, Vector3[0].y = 4, Vector3[0].z = 0,
Vector3[1].x = 5,.. I want to access to every Vector3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
var vectors;
var koloader = new THREE.FileLoader();
koloader.load('https://cywarr.github.io/small-shop/example.txt', (data) => {

  vectors = data.split('\n').map(line => {
    let l = line.split(' ');
    return new THREE.Vector3(parseFloat(l[0]), parseFloat(l[1]), parseFloat(l[2]));
  }).filter((vector) => {
    return typeof vector !== 'undefined'
  });

  console.log(vectors[0].x, vectors[0].y, vectors[0].z);
  console.log(vectors[1].x, vectors[1].y, vectors[1].z);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/100/three.min.js"></script>
```

After this, the `vectors` variable will be an array of `THREE.Vector3()`, thus you'll be able to access their values by indices and names of fields (x, y, z).

Comment: my data is in txt is like: 121.21 241.11 133.12\n
                                     123.43 211.33 123.11 and output it right now with example: console.log(kord[0].x);

Comment: @JoeBRock I've updated the answer, using `THREE.FileLoader()`. The result is an array of `THREE.Vector3()`. If the answer solved your problem, mark it as accepted, please.